# How to upload images to Blogger Blogspot posts?

Tags: python, upload, blogger

I'm using the API given here from Google, https://developers.google.com/blogger/docs/3.0/using . It allows managing the Blogger blogs easily. The problem is that the content that this API accepts is an HTML content. So, I must provide it with:

```
<h1> title <title>
<p> Hello,</br> how are you doing today</p>
...
```

So, to integrate an image on the post I must upload it to another image uploader service then get the URL and add it to a `<img>` tag.
In contrast, if I want to upload the image directly to the Blogger UI, the image will be uploaded to Google servers.

My question is: How can I upload images to Google servers as the Blogger UI do, then integrate them into my posts?

Answer (score 1):

I too have been trying to work around this issue. What I did in the end is to use [Google Drive API](https://developers.google.com/drive) to upload the image and then get a shareable URL and embed it in the blog post.

This comes with its drawbacks, the photos are slower to load on the blog and is not accessible to crawlers. But works as far as the requirement is concerned.

If you find any way to get it done through Blogger API or through Google Photos API, please do let me know.

Comment: Could you show us how you did it?  I've tried using the HTML Blogger editor to add images from both Drive and Photos to a blog post but neither of them work.

Comment: I integrated the Google Drive API into my project using which I could upload the images to a folder and set its sharing permissions to public. Once the sharing permissions are set, the API would return a public URL to the image. I replaced the original image in the blog post with this URL.

You can refer to the my Github repository if you like: https://github.com/aswinrajeev/blogly